# How do I prevent VisualStudio from prepending namespace to TypeLib coclass name?

Tags: .net, vb.net, com, vb6, visual-studio-2013

I have a COM Callable Wrapper that has worked up until now.

Now I get a "user defined type not defined" error when I try to compile my VB6 application which depends on it. Things that have changed include the COM Callable Wrapper being moved from .Net Framework 2 to 4 and I am using VS2013 now instead of VS2010. There are some changes to code but none which  I can see as being responsible.

When I look at the generated typelib in oleview.exe and compare it to the previous version I see the the namespace (with underscores) has been prepended to two of my coclasses so that I now have `coclass CompanyName_Compatibility_Field` where before I had just `coclass Field` which I assume is the cause of my problems.

I have always had a reference to classic ADODB primary interop assembly but now i have an `importlib("msado15.dll");` statement in the generated typelib where previously I did not and the typelib now includes enum definitions for a number of ADODB enum types where previously it did not.

Is ADODB the reason why the namespace is now being prepended to my `Field` object and is there a way I can prevent this and exclude ADODB stuff from the typelib?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the **Embed Interop Types** property for the ADODB reference and an Active Reports reference (which also has a `Field` object) and now my VB6 application compiles.
I confess I was unaware of this property. It must have changed when I re-added some references after moving from framework 2 to 4.